# FlashMode enumerator values

Tags: flash, windows-phone-8, camera

something strange happened to me.. I've wrote following code:

```
IReadOnlyList<object> supportedFlashModes = PhotoCaptureDevice.GetSupportedPropertyValues(CameraSensorLocation.Front, KnownCameraPhotoProperties.FlashMode);

_availableStates = new FlashStates();
foreach (uint supportedFlashMode in supportedFlashModes)
{
    _availableStates.Add(
        new FlashState() { State = (FlashMode)supportedFlashMode }
     );
 }
```

The result is : 0, 1, 3

But FlashMode Enum values are: 1,2,3 and 4.. There is not the 0 value! So when I try to check if the Off mode (value = 0) with this code

```
_availableStates.Exists(fs => fs.State == mode);
```

it returns FALSE, should return TRUE instead...

How can be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FlashMode property is of type FlashState which has Enum values of 0, 1 and 3.

FlashMode documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.knowncameraphotoproperties.flashmode(v=vs.105).aspx

FlashState enum: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.flashstate(v=vs.105).aspx

I hope that helps.

Comment: AHhhh I'm really stupid... I was wrong with this:
[FlashMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.flashmode(v=vs.105).aspx)...
So how can I set RedEyeReduction? If flash is available can user set R-E-R (if he/she wants to)?